# TestCafe doesn't allow chrome component PNaCl to load

Tags: google-chrome

When running TestCafe via CLI or VSCode extension, the component Pnacl does not load.  It just has Version - 0.0.0.0.  If I set a debug point within TestCafe, I can manually go to chrome://components and click on 'check for update' button.  This loads the component and my PDFviewer then displays the PDF file that is required in my website.

Anyone know how to allow TestCafe to allow this component to install?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, TestCafe launches browsers (Google Chrome and Mozilla Firefox so far) with a clean profile, i.e. without extensions, bookmarks and other profile settings. This was done to minimize the influence of profile parameters on test runs.

However, if you need to start a browser with the current user profile, you can do this by specifying [the :userProfile flag](https://devexpress.github.io/testcafe/documentation/using-testcafe/common-concepts/browsers/user-profiles.html) after the browser alias.

Comment: Thank you very much!  This helped a a lot